# Combining promises in Angular 2

Tags: angular, promise

Is there any way to combine promises in AngularJS 2?
In Angular 1, for instance, I would use `$q.all` to combine multiple requests into a single promise.
Is there an equivalent for Angular 2?

Comment: $q.all did not chain promises, but combined them to resolve when all of them resolved, or reject when the first one rejected. There is no meaning of the order of promises here. You have Promise.all to do the same job.

Comment: My mistake; I've updated the title and question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The http module works in terms of Observables which is different than promises, but you can do both chaining and parallel calls.

Chaining can be done using flatMap and parallel calls can be handled using forkJoin.

Examples:

```
//dependent calls (chaining)
this.http.get('./customer.json').map((res: Response) => {
                   this.customer = res.json();
                   return this.customer;
                })
                .flatMap((customer) => this.http.get(customer.contractUrl)).map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => this.contract = res);

//parallel
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('./friends.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('./customer.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(res => this.combined = {friends:res[0].friends, customer:res[1]});
```

You can find more details and a demo here:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

You can also call `toPromise()` on an Observable and convert it to a regular promise as well.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using Observables for Angular 2+ but in case you still need to use Promises you can use the following:

```
Promise.all(
      [
         promise1,
         promise2, 
         promise3
      ]
);
```