# ngrx sum up observable.from() results

Tags: observable, ngrx

I'm facing an issue with observable.from().
I have an array of ID's and for each ID I need to perform an async operation and return a value.

I want after all of the ID's complete their inner async operation to get the value of all of them together (Not one by one).

This is my code:

```
Observable.from(IDs)
        .mergeMap(ID=> this.getDataByID(ID)
          .map(data => Observable.of(Object.assign({}, data, dataUpdate[ID]))))
        .subscribe(newData=> {
          ...
        })
```

The dataUpdate is an object from outside of this scope witch hold data I want to append to the object fetched by getDataByID().

In this case the subscriber been called for every event ID and newData contains the data for only one ID.

Can I make the newData to hold an object/array of all of the data instead of one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you will need to use another RxJS operator , such as forkjoin
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin

You can take a look at this as well 
[Multiple ajax call in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158142/multiple-ajax-call-in-angular2/45158225#45158225)

Comment: Can you please show me where should I add this operator ?